# C# WPF ckeckbox to keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a check box in my window, I want when the user clicks it works as if the user clicks on the ALT key on keyboard. How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but this sounds like a scary UI.

Comment: @Yuriy: why is that? I have a button which when the user click acts as it the user is clicking the ALT button. My application is intended to work on touch screens with no keyboard or mouse

Comment: I could see that working as a hard lock for the alt button, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three mechanisms which you could leverage.

1) Raise the KeyDown event for your control manually.

2) Perhaps look into the [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx)  class.

3) Or you could P/Invoke to [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(VS.85).aspx).